# Dynamic poll plugin for J2ee web application not PHP

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jakarta-ee

I am looking for a dynamic **POLL plugin** to my website ,but there is no such plugin available with j2ee .All i have found is for PHP .Can anyone knows any plugin for J2ee(Java) .

I can use either xml or mysql for data in polling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Portal/Open-Portal/com/sun/portal/sample/j2ee/poll/ejb/Poll.java.htm)?

Comment: Humm... Looks like they are rearranging the site -- try this search https://www.google.com/search?q=POLL+plugin+j2ee+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.java2s.com&qscrl=1